# Which is commoner here: Past Simple or Past Perfect?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

For a native speaker of English, which construction is commoner ?

1- The interviewer asked me which university l went to.

2- The interviewer asked me which university l had been to.

Thanks.

Comment: What's up with the lowercase L's? "which university *L* went to"

Comment: What was the interviewer's question: _Which university do you go to?_ (i.e., you are still at university). Or _Which university did you go to?_ (i.e., you are no longer at university)

Comment: @Shoe: You mean both constructions are Ok depending on the the question being asked by the interviewer?

Comment: If it is the first question, then only the first of your two sentences is correct. If it is the second question, then both of your sentences are possible, but the first is probably more common. If you edit your post to make it clear which direct speech question you are asking about with your two indirect speech versions, then I will provide a proper answer.

Comment: @Shoe: l really appreciate your comment. It's very clear now and I got the difference between the two constructions.